# How can I go to directory using git command?

Tags: git

I need to create git repository in my wamp server folder path but here while installing it has been setting the program files path.

Comment: Just create a folder and run git init to create a repo.

Answer (score 1):

So `cd` to the folder, and do:

```
$ git init
```

voila.